# How to initiate the trigger in Workflow Rule in salesforce

Tags: trigger

How to invoke the trigger using Workflow rule in salesforce.Please anyone guide me for the answer.Is it possible or not

Answer (score 2):

Check [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

10. Executes workflow rules.
11. If there are workflow field updates, updates the record again.
12. If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again.

After workflow execution, if there are field updates the record gets update again. Doing so, the respective triggers will get executed.

**Note: You can not invoke Trigger code directly from workflow rule. The workflow field update causes record to execute its trigger only once.**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initiate a trigger in a workflow rule. What you can do is to write your trigger to fire on a particular condition of the record. Then via workflow you can help the record to reach trigger criteria. But this all depends on what you want to achieve and the condition in your trigger can be reached via workflow or not.

Comment: i am not understand please explain ellaborately @Ruchi

Comment: You know my problem what i am facing @Ruchi,guide me the Answer path

Comment: A trigger will fire on the record for a particular condition whichever you specify in it. So if possible you can create your workflow rule to reach the trigger condition to make it fire.

Answer (score 0):

You trigger should must be on create/Update event(Delete will not work). Then create a workflow on everytime create/update on same object(on which you have written trigger) which will have some simple criteria(Like some required field is not null). And try to update/create some field.